# Writing a Simple LINQ Query

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

So I've been living in the dark ages of iterating through my data and finding what I'm interested the old fashioned way, but this project I thought I should make things more elegant and use LINQ where I know it can be used, but things aren't quite clicking.

So I have two simple ObservableCollections and I want to pull all the data from one of them matching the current selected item of the other.  The objects are very simple...

```
public class foo
{
    //....
    public string barID{ get; set; }
    //....
}

public class bar
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    //....
}
```

So in my code I have the selected foo, and I want to create a collection of all bar's that have the matching barID...

```
ObservableCollection<bar> bars = 
    from data in fooCollection
    where data.barID == barCollection.SelectedItem.ID
    select data;
```

So I tried this based on the syntax for LINQ I was finding online, but this throws a compile error of unable to implicitly cast IEnumerable to ObservableCollection.  So I tried...

```
ObservableCollection<bar> bars = 
    (ObservableCollection<bar>)
    (from data in fooCollection
    where data.barID == barCollection.SelectedItem.ID
    select data);
```

Which compiles but throws a run-time error...

```
Unable to cast object of type 
'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[TestProj.bar]' to type 
'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[TestProj.bar]'.
```

So I'm sure I could cast the object after the fact or do something else, but I was looking for as elegant a solution as possible, so a little help getting this simple LINQ statement together would be appreciated.  Also a simple explanation of what is happening behind the scenes would help immensely in helping me understand some of the LINQ basics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just use the [ObservableCollection constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679169).

```
IEnumerable<bar> barEnumerable = 
    from data in fooCollection
    where data.barID == barCollection.SelectedItem.ID
    select data;

ObservableCollection<bar> bars = new ObservableCollection<bar>(barEnumerable);
```

What's going on is basically:

```
IEnumerable<bar> barEnumerable = 
fooCollection.Where(data => data.barID == barCollection.SelectedItem.ID);
```

Comment: Any particular reason this works, but casting it throws an error?

Comment: Because it's the output of the query is an Enumerable and not an ObservableCollection so you need to construct an ObservableCollection from the Enumerable.

Comment: @KDiTraglia `Converting` and `Casting` are two very different things.  Casting is telling the compiler, "I know you think this variable is an X, but I happen to know better than you and know that it's really a Y, stick it in a variable of type Y".  If the variable isn't actually a Y it'll break.  Converting is saying, "Here is some code that when given a Y as input will return an X as output", thus giving you an entirely new value that is of the type that you want.  Since you really do have an `IEnumerable`, which isn't an `ObservableCollection`, you need to *Convert* it, not *Cast* it.

Comment: @Servy, that's a good explanation, except that `ObservableCollection` doesn't implement `IObservable`.

Comment: @Servy good explanation, but I think my confusion stems from the fact that my initial data I'm 'LINQ'ing is an ObservableCollection, so I was thinking the cast would be implicit (I started with this data I want it to come back out).  Is IEnumerable just always the type output whenever LINQ is ever used?

Comment: @KDiTraglia, for `Select`/, it is `IEnumerable<T>` for Linq to Objects (which you're using), and `IQueryable<T>` for other Linq providers.  See [`Enumable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx).

Comment: @KDiTraglia Not *always* but usually, yes.  You are not modifying whatever it is you're using the LINQ methods on, and you're (usually) not getting a new collection of the same type back.  You get just an `IEnumerable` (or an "iterator" to be more general).  Exceptions are methods like `ToArray`, `ToList`, (everything else that starts with "To"),  `First`, all of the ordering methods (they return interfaces that extend IEnumerable), the aggregate methods (min/max/average).

Answer (score 2):

Casting changes the type of the expression, it will work if the expression really is that type.

Consider `class Customer : Person`

```
Customer c = new Customer();
Person p = c;  //no problem;  this is an implicit up-cast (from child to parent)
Customer c2 = p;  //compiler doesn't allow because
                  //p may refer to a Person instance that isn't a Customer
Customer c3 = (Customer) p; //we certify to the compiler that p is referencing
                            //a Customer instance, and we take responsibility
                            //for an exception if we are wrong.
                            // this is a down-cast (from parent to child)
Customer cSafe = p as Customer; //safe down-cast, we get a null in cSafe if we are wrong
```

Due to the potential for exceptions, down-casts are extremely rare in my code.  Let's take a moment to thank Generics for making that possible.  Ok, on to conversion:

Conversion creates a new instance of the desired type from the old instance.

```
Customer c4 = new Customer(p); //conversion constructor
Customer c5 = p.ToCustomer(); //conversion method
Customer c6 = (Customer) p; // if defined, implicit conversion. Otherwise, casting
                            // yes, casting and implicit conversion are the same syntax
                            // terribly confusing.
```

---

We know from the exception message that the instance returned by the query is a `WhereEnumerableIterator<TestProj.bar>`.

This result instance isn't an array, it isn't a `List<T>`, and it isn't an `ObservableCollection<T>`.  A cast can't work, because `ObservableCollection<T>` does not inherit from `WhereEnumerableIterator<T>`.  If you want an `ObservableCollection<T>` from it, you need to convert.

Behind the syntax, that query is calling `Enumerable.Where` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx)), which returns an `IEnumerable<T>`.  The simplest way to convert from that type to the desired type is to use the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679169.aspx) for `ObservableCollection<T>`.

Answer (score -4):

You could simply use "var" as your bars type:

```
var bars = from data in fooCollection
where data.barID == fooCollection.SelectedItem.ID
select data;
```

Comment: That just pushes the problem down until later; eventually the `IEnumerable` result of the LINQ query must be turned into an `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: Sure, but sometimes one doesn't even need to know about it. Depends on what you want to do with the result, for example simple enumeration using foreach wouldn't require any casting, since only IEnumerable is required.

Comment: Except he said he wanted an `ObservableCollection`.  That isn't one, and it doesn't implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` or `INotifyPropertyChanged` either.  `var` is primarily for when you know what you're typing, you just want to type it in fewer characters.  It's not to push the type problem under the covers.